# Site caching a php page?

Tags: caching

I recently 'inherited' a website which has a Drupal installation on it. I know absolutely nothing about Drupal. I don't want to go on for too long, but the site is an absolute mess. It looks like there are two separate websites there that interweave. In all honesty, I dont think I could have paid someone to make a less understandable website. None of the code is documented, there is just no sense to any of it.

Well here's my problem -

I recently changed all of the FTP, SQL and site passwords so the previous ownership couldn't access the site.

On one of the pages there is a PHP script that processes a form. In the form, the php accesses a file called, "login_credentials.php" (sigh...) which contains the SQL login info.

Now, whenever someone tries to use the page, there is an error that says invalid password on line 12. I, of course, have gone into the login_credentials.php file and confirmed that the password is the new password.

I also went in and even changed the code so that the SQL connection is on a different line (line 13) but the error still says line 12. This is telling me that the page is somehow cached (maybe?), but I have no idea how.

What's even stranger is that if you are logged into the site as an admin, the error DOES NOT occur. This problem only occurs to the public. (only admins need to log in).

I honestly can't say what the problem is. I'm only moderately savvy when it comes to php/html etc, and know nothing at all about Drupal.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you cleared cache yet? If not, go to the URL below to clear the sites cache. See if the error changes like you expected.

- Drupal 6: /admin/settings/performance/drupal
- Drupal 7: /admin/config/development/performance

It could also be that you changed the password of the SQL user that Drupal uses to operate, in which case you would need to update that information in **/sites/yoursite/settings.php**

What version of Drupal are you using?

Comment: I can't seem to find the first two paths you listed. I verified the login at settings.php and it seems to be correct. ( the site allows me to make layout changes and create pages so I assume that means it's working?) I have no idea what version of Drupal it is.

Comment: If you manually want to clear cache just Empty the cache tables in the database: (tables with names that start with cache)